# Asymptotic number of $3$-AP's in a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ of density $\epsilon$.

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

**Problem:** Let $p$ be an odd prime number and consider the $n$-dimensional vector space over the field with $p$ elements. I want to prove that the number of $3$-term arithmetic progressions in a subset
$A\subseteq\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ is $cp^{2n}$ for every $n\geq N_{0}$, for sufficiently large $N_{0}$ and a constant $c>0$.

**Fact 1:** I shall use Meshulam's theorem which states that if a subset $B\subseteq\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ has density bigger than $2/n$, i.e. $|B|> \frac{2p^{n}}{n}$, then $Β$ contains a $3$-term arithmetic progression.

**Fact 2:** I also may use the following fact: First observe that if $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$, then there are $p^{n-k}$ distinct cosets of $U$.
Now, let $A\subseteq\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ be a subset of density $\epsilon>0$.
Then, there are at least $\frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{n-k}$ cosets $V$ of $U$ such that $|A\cap V|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{k}$.

As an affine subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ is just a coset of a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$, we have that the above implies that there exist at least $\frac{\epsilon}{2}f(k,n)$ $k$-dimensinal affine subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ such that $|A\cap V|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{k}$, where $f(k,n)$ is the total number of the $k$-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$. This number equals to
\begin{equation}
f(k,n)=p^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}_{p}
\end{equation}
where $\binom{n}{k}_{p}$ is the Gaussian coefficient and id defined as
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k}_{p}=\frac{(p^{n}-1)(p^{n}-p)\cdots(p^{n}-p^{k-1})}{(p^{k}-1)(p^{k}-p)\cdots (p^{k}-p^{k-1})}.
\end{equation}

---

My attempt goes as follows: Let $n$ be large enough so that there exists $k<n$ such that $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>\frac{2}{k}$. Then, we consider $p^{n-k}$
$k$-dimensional affine subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ pairwise disjoint (we can take such by taking the $p^{n-k}$ of a $k$-dimensional subspace). We know that there $\frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{n-k}$ of them such that $|A\cap V|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{k}>\frac{2p^{k}}{k}$. Then, considering each $A\cap V$ as a subspace of $V\cong\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$, Meshulam's theorem implies that each one of them contains a $3$-AP and since they are pairwise disjoint there are $\frac{\epsilon}{2}p^{n-k}$ $3$-AP's in $A$.

That is as far as I get. My idea is to use the more powerful statement of **Fact 2**, where by finding $cp^{2n}$ disjoint $k$-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ it implies the desired. But I have no clue how to find them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is in your fact 2. What should be true is that:
Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{F}^n_p$ be a subset of density $\varepsilon>0$. Then, at least an $ϵ/2$ fraction of all $k$-dimensional subspaces $V$ is such that $|A\cap V|≥(ϵ/2)p^k$.

Then you can consider this fraction of subspaces $\varepsilon/2\binom{n}{k}_p$, in general not disjoint, for your $k$. Each of this will contain a 3AP by Meshulam. Now you just have to be careful about overcounting. The maximum times you may have overcounted an AP is the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces that pass through a 3AP, which is just 3 aligned points in $\mathbb{F}_p^n$. Dividing by this number should give you the desired bound.

Comment: Oh, this is nice. I hadn't thought of taking only the $k$-dimensional subspaces. How one counts the $k$-dimensional subspaces passing through a 3-AP though?

Comment: The hint is that a 3AP defines itself a 1-dimensional affine subspace, being a line. In how many ways can you complete this to an affine k-dimensional subspace? You already have a formula for that.

Comment: Yeah right. Thanks!